# Shopify Error: Section id 'custom-product-recommendations' must exist in order

Tags: shopify

Facing the issue while adding custom product recommendations in the product.json file in **Shopify**.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

After adding the sections, if you are getting the out-of-order error. Look at the bottom of the product.json and you should have an "order" array.

Within this order array, you should list them in the same order they exist above this array, for example if something comes before "Main" add this in before Main following the array notation.

[Example of Order Array img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2QqA.png)

Comment: Can you add your image file as written code to your answer? Links can always get broken in the future

Answer (score 0):

You must follow alphabetical order while adding any section id in a product JSON file.